# Adding helper text under a button

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm currently trying to achieve this.
[image]

I'm trying to add a helper text to the button. But I'm having a hard time this is my current code.

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
     <Button
           android:id="@+id/login_btnLogin"
           android:layout_width="412dp"
           android:layout_height="90dp"
           android:layout_gravity="center"
           android:background="@color/myGreen"
           android:text="Continue"
           android:textAllCaps="false"
           android:textSize="30sp"
           android:textColor="@color/ghostWhiteColor" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: One of the solutions could be using a RelativeLayout and just a TextView on top of the button

Comment: sample image is not a button.that is layout or custom button. you can use layout to button with setOnClickListener.

Comment: https://github.com/medyo/Fancybuttons. you can easily implement custom button this lib.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="90dp">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:text="Verify"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="By preceding verify I agree terms and conditions."
        android:textColor="#fff" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Use linaer layout instead of button.

<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
     <LinearLayout
           android:id="@+id/login_btnLogin"
           android:layout_width="412dp"
           android:layout_height="90dp"
           android:layout_gravity="center"
           android:background="@color/myGreen">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
             android:text="Continue"
           android:textAllCaps="false"
           android:textSize="30sp"
           android:textColor="@color/ghostWhiteColor" />

   <TextVie
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
             android:text="click to continue..."
           android:textAllCaps="false"
           android:textSize="30sp"
           android:textColor="@color/ghostWhiteColor" />
</LinearLayout>
```